# Logging in on frontend with a customer associated to "Admin" (website)

Tags: customer

Is a customer assigned to `Admin` for the `Associate to Website` in the admin supposed to be able to log in on the frontend? If not, what is this account for? I can't seem to log on with a customer I made in the admin with website association to `admin`. This customer has `website_id = 0` and `store_id = 0`.

Some background:

I have a set of customer migrated by someone else, and all of them have `website_id = 1`, which is correct, but the `store_id`s are all set to zero. Subsequently, they show up having `Admin` for their `Associate to Website` value in the admin. This seems to have been done incorrectly, as I don't think you can get the combination of values `website_id  = 1` and `store_id = 0`.

Can someone verify?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create a user via the admin section with `Associate to Website => Admin`. Then the following will be true:

1. store_id = 0,
2. website_id = 0,
3. User wont be able to log into front end :(

If you create a user via the admin section with `Associate to website => Some Store`. Then the following will be true.

1. store_id = 0,
2. website_id = 1, where 1 is the id of the website under 'Associate to website'
3. They will be able to log into the front end for that website.

If under `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Account Sharing Options` you set this option to global than no matter what store the account was set-up on the user will be able to login. If you have this set to a website level then you can create more than one account with the same email address as long ass the associated websites are different.

Comment: Did the same but not working....!

Answer (score 1):

An order could be placed for that customer in the Admin, but not in the frontend.